# C# - IAsyncCompletionSource - asynchronous call to third party ? how to re trigger the autocompletion properly?

Tags: c#

I need to produce code completion session in a VSIX, but it seems the API is not keen to asynchronous requests to third party servers

If I provide local test values, I get a completion popup

```
        public async Task<CompletionContext> GetCompletionContextAsync(IAsyncCompletionSession session, CompletionTrigger trigger, SnapshotPoint triggerLocation, SnapshotSpan applicableToSpan, CancellationToken token)
        {
            List<CompletionItem> items = new List<CompletionItem>();
            items.Add(MakeItemFromElement("test1", "test1", "test1"));
            items.Add(MakeItemFromElement("test2", "test2", "test2"));
            items.Add(MakeItemFromElement("test3", "test3", "test3"));
            var results = new CompletionContext(items.ToImmutableArray());
        }
```

Using a request to a remote server that would, in turn, return a similar array, the popup never shows up

```
        public async Task<CompletionContext> GetCompletionContextAsync(IAsyncCompletionSession session, CompletionTrigger trigger, SnapshotPoint triggerLocation, SnapshotSpan applicableToSpan, CancellationToken token)
        {

            // this does not work 
            List<CompletionItem> items = new List<CompletionItem>();
            var results = new CompletionContext(items.ToImmutableArray());

            if (!Connector.isEnabled())
                return results;

            try
            {
                items = await completionRequestAsync(session, triggerLocation);
                results = new CompletionContext(items.ToImmutableArray());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.LogException(e);
            }

            // here we have the results from the server, but no completion is showing up
            if (results.Items != null)
            {
                Logger.Log($"completionContext.Items count {results.Items.Length}");
                foreach (CompletionItem item in results.Items)
                {
                    Logger.Loge($"Completion result: {item.DisplayText}");
                }
            }
            
            return results;
        }
```

Am I missing anything ?

here is the initialization

```
    public CompletionStartData InitializeCompletion(CompletionTrigger trigger, SnapshotPoint triggerLocation, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // We don't trigger completion when user typed
        if (char.IsNumber(trigger.Character)         // a number
            || char.IsPunctuation(trigger.Character) // punctuation
            || trigger.Character == '\n'             // new line
            || trigger.Reason == CompletionTriggerReason.Backspace
            || trigger.Reason == CompletionTriggerReason.Deletion)
        {
            return CompletionStartData.DoesNotParticipateInCompletion;
        }
        var tokenSpan = FindTokenSpanAtPosition(triggerLocation);
        return new CompletionStartData(CompletionParticipation.ExclusivelyProvidesItems, tokenSpan);
    }
```

I tried ExclusivelyProvidesItems or ProvidesItems, does not seem to help

any help appreciated